# Stop git flow from creating a tag automatically

Tags: git, git-flow

When I found some bugs in my project,I created a hotfix branch:

```
git flow hotfix start fixSomeBug
```

When I did some changes and commits,I wanted to merge these commits to master,so I typed

```
git flow hotfix finish fixSomeBug
```

Next I needed to write three messages:

- Write a message for merging to master
- Write a message for tag: fixSomeBug
- Write a message for merging to develop

That was fine,but I didn't want to create a tag named fixSomeBug automatically.

So what can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the -n operator. From the [docs](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#git-flow-hotfix-finish--fsumpkn-version)

> **-n** don't tag this release

So the command will be like this

```
git flow hotfix finish -n fixSomeBug
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to not tag an individual hotfix you can use the `-n` flag:

`git flow hotfix finish -n fixSomeBug`

If you want to have the default not to be tagged you can set this config:

`git config gitflow.hotfix.finish.notag true`